# Is there a way to have an outlook 2007 email template automatically update the subject with the current date?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, templates, macros

I send out an email every morning in a specific format.

To = The same group every day

Subject = `"Scrum 25-SEP-09"` (replace the date with the current date)

Body =

```
Yesterday:
     - <what I did yesterday>
Today:
     - <what I did today>
Roadblocks:
     - <stuff in my way of getting things done>
```

I would like to save this as an email template that I can quickly edit every day and send it out.

My question:
Is there a way to have an outlook 2007 email template automatically update the subject with the current date?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Select *Design a Form*. from the *Tools\Forms* menu

In the *Standard Forms Library* Open the *Message* form.  This will open a standard mail form.

Right-click on the Subject text input box and select *Properties*.

From the Properties dialogue box click on the *Value* tab.
Edit the initial value and enter:

```
'Scrum ' & Date()
```

You can then make any other changes you want to the form and test it with the *Run this Form* option.

If you are happy with the result you are ready to Publish.  Select the *Publish* option and select *Publish Form As..* and save it in your Personal Forms Library.

When you want to use it you can select it from File\New\Choose Form and open it from your 'Personal Forms Library' (there may be a quicker way to do this)

Comment: Seems to work. Is there a way to distribute that so others can use the same form?

Comment: If you are using outlook in an Exchange environment then you could publish to the Organisational Forms Library.  Otherwise you can save the form as an .oft file and distribute to other users.